# Using spritecollide in Pygame - with rotated surfaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite

I have created a surface that is intended to be used as a 'wall' for an rpg style game, however I rotated this surface so it takes the form of a diamond since this is how the game design looks. My question is when using spritecollide it only works in rect arguments (rectangles). How can I make a 'wall' surface that has been rotated and essentially gives a rotated rect argument for a diamond? Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use collision masks for anything more complex than a rectangle or circle.
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask